# TextFormField not gaining focus when pressed

Tags: flutter

When this TextFormField is pressed on, it does not gain focus. Here is my code for the widget containing the TextFormField

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:cyphlyfe/profile/notifiers/profileNotifier.dart';

class Bio extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pNotifier = Provider.of<ProfileNotifier>(context);
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 15,
        left: 30,
        right: 30,
      ),
      child: pNotifier.editMode ? TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        initialValue: pNotifier.profileInfo['bio'],
        maxLengthEnforced: true,
        maxLength: 140,
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Write your bio here'),
        onChanged: (value) => pNotifier.updateProfileInfo('bio', value),
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
        ),
      ) : Text(
        pNotifier.profileInfo['bio'].isEmpty
            ? 'You have no bio. Add one!'
            : pNotifier.profileInfo['bio'],
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey.shade600,
          fontSize: 16,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the button that toggles editMode (causing the TextFormField to appear)

```
import 'package:cyphlyfe/profile/notifiers/profileNotifier.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ButtonEdit extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ButtonEditState createState() => _ButtonEditState();
}

class _ButtonEditState extends State<ButtonEdit> {
  ProfileNotifier pNotifier;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    pNotifier = Provider.of<ProfileNotifier>(context);
    return pNotifier.editMode ? IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.check),
      onPressed: onSave,
    ) : IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
      onPressed: onEdit,
    );
  }

  void onEdit() {
    pNotifier.editMode = true;
  }

  Future<void> onSave() async {
    // todo: upload profile pic to firebase storage
    // todo: send profileInfo data in pNotifier to user service to update user record
    pNotifier.editMode = false;
    _showSavedSnackBar();

  }

  void _showSavedSnackBar() {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.check_circle,
            color: Colors.green,
            size: 24.0,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 5.0),
          Text("Changes saved successfully.")
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Also, here's the parent widget

```
import 'package:cyphlyfe/profile/widgets/appName.dart';
import 'package:cyphlyfe/profile/widgets/backdrop.dart';
import 'package:cyphlyfe/profile/widgets/bio.dart';
import 'package:cyphlyfe/profile/widgets/btnVideoCall.dart';
import 'package:cyphlyfe/profile/widgets/name.dart';
import 'package:cyphlyfe/profile/widgets/profileAppBar.dart';
import 'package:cyphlyfe/profile/widgets/profilePic.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Backdrop(),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 90),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  AppName(),
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  ProfilePic(),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Name(),
                  Bio(),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  ButtonVideoCall(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            ProfileAppBar(),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

In case it's relevant, minSdkVersion is 16, compileSdkVersion is 28, and targetSdkVersion is 28. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was the order of the widgets in the Stack. The ProfileAppBar was being displayed on top of the Container, blocking the gesture detection of the Container's child widgets. I put ProfileAppBar before the Container and everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass a focus node to TextFormField widget
2. When Button pressed just call **myFocusNode.requestFocus()**

[Ref](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus)

Comment: From what I understand, the focus node is to give access to the TextFormField on the click of a button or some other event right? What's happening on my end is that when the TextFormField itself is clicked on, it does not retrieve focus. I have tried wrapping the TextFormField in a GestureDetector and requesting focus on tap, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Jaleel Have you try change Bio stateless widget to stateful widget?

Comment: yup I did, got the same result